# Logicool M555b Bluetooth mouse, Lenovo Y580, Bluetooth connection drops

Tags: windows-7, mouse, bluetooth, lenovo-laptop

Any ideas on this?

When I leave my Bluetooth mouse untouched for some time, the connection drops.  Moving the mouse and cycling its power don't solve the problem.

If I open the wireless/Bluetooth control panel (Fn + F5 on Lenovo) and cycle the Bluetooth power, the connection will restart.

The driver is up to date.  I can't find any resources on Lenovo's site or through Google in general.  Any ideas??

Comment: connection drop as in wifi connection ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its totally related to power settings that WIFI by default inherit when associated with an operating system, in this case, Windows 7/8.

I am saying this referring to a problem that occured when I first used my HP Pav g6 2313AX, the wifi was lost after inactivity. Only turning on and off wifi would work or trouble shoot.

Since then I keep an habit of changing the power setting to my own setting.

Here is what you can try :

Go into your network settings.
Control panel again
Mouse to the bottom-right, ‘Search’ again. 
This time type “Control panel” and click the result. From here we want “Network and Internet” and then “Network and Sharing Center” and from there “Change adapter settings” (It’s on the left hand menubar)

**This is important part**

*Right click your wifi adapter -> click Properties -> click Configure -> click Power Management*

*Uncheck the box “Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power”. That should do the job.*

Worked for me. :)

Comment: Pradip, thanks!!  I had checked the bluetooth settings, but had no idea that there was a related setting in the wireless area.  Go windows? :[  So far your advice seems to be working, so thanks a bunch!

Comment: @user257286.. Windows do come with some of the annoying features.. nyways glad I could help.